# Is there a way to catch errors from mixing meter_t and mile_t?

Tags: c++, c++17

Can the compiler be made to flag type problems in the following code?

```
typedef float meter_t;
typedef float mile_t;

meter_t alpha = 100;
mile_t beta = 200;

if (alpha == beta) // Should be flagged
{
   mile_t gamma = alpha;  // Should be flagged
   mile_t delta = static_cast<mile_t>(alpha);  // Should be allowed
}
```

I would like to use typedefs to help prevent errors using different units. I don't want to incur the performance penalty of implementing wrapper types. A compiler warning would be perfect.

Comment: Why do you believe there's going to be a "performance penalty"? I expect all current C++ compilers to optimize away all the overhead of a simple wrapper type, with basic, inline, overloads.

Comment: Just giving different names to the same type doesn't make them different. Maybe [user defined literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal).

Comment: you cannot use typdefs to prevent errors using different units. `meter_t` and `mile_t` are the same type

Comment: No, typedefs don't create a new type (just an extra name for the same type). So the types are the same. And there is no performance penalty for a wrapper type (just some work in writing operator overloads).

Comment: It's not possible to create a "strong typedef" that without creating a wrapper class. `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF` does exactly that, wrapped in a neat macro.

Comment: I've changed the typedefs one at a time to double and recompiled to get the warnings I am looking for. This is not ideal, but it is fairly effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can the compiler be made to flag type problems in the following code?

No. `typedef` merely introduces an alias. It does not define a new type. Concerning the types, your code is equivalent to

```
float alpha = 100;
float beta = 200;

if (alpha == beta) // Should be flagged
{
   float gamma = alpha;  // Should be flagged
   float delta = static_cast<float>(alpha);  // Should be allowed
}
```

And there is no way to make the compiler warn about mixing `float` with `float`.

> I don't want to incur the performance penalty of implementing wrapper types.

Don't bother about performance penalty before there actually is one. It is not obvious why you expect a performance penalty from using wrapper types. Its not expected to incur significant overhead to introduce types with the proper explicit conversions (and forbidden implicit conversions).

---

For inspiration you might want to take a look at how `chrono` defines durations via `std::ratio`. For a ready to use solution look for boosts `BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF`.